# why my facebook share button is disabling facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

my facebook share button is disabling facebook like button

**code for like button i wrote is**

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=308804365831102";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://www.interactivebees.com/"      data-send="false"  
    data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

**code for share button is**

```
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"         
    data-url="http://www.interactivebees.com/" 
    data-via="http://www.interactivebees.com/" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>

    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)  [0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id; 
    js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are saying that facebook share button is disabling facebook like button but you have given the code for tweet share and facebook like...and both the things are working fine together for me...